# In mediawiki, Add noscript tag to enable script

Tags: javascript, php, mediawiki

I am doing site in mediawiki, I have used so many javascript, so if the javascript is enable only i can able to see the mediawiki pages. And i am using the skins as vector. I need to  know how to add the noscript tag in header in mediawiki for display the error if javascript is disabled . Kindly suggest any solution

Comment: Edit the vector skin files.

Comment: Thanks for ur info. i need to know how to add the script in vector.php file to add that in header part.

Answer (score 1):

Two approaches:

1. Rather that alter the skin (and loose your changes on the next update), you could write a simple extensions that does what you want. That will be more future-proof, and also work no matter what skin the user has in their user preferences.
   There are a number of [hooks](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aHooks) your could use. to get the noscript-message to appear below the title, you could use the [`SkinSubPageSubtitle`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aHooks/SkinSubPageSubtitle) hook. The extension would then look somthing like this:

   ```
   $wgHooks['SkinSubPageSubtitle'][] = 'fnAddNoScript';

   function fnAddNoScript(&$subpages,$skin) { 

       $subpages .= Html::element('noscript',null, $yourMessage );

       return true; 
   }
   ```
2. MediaWiki adds the class `client-nojs` to the `<html>` tag when rendering a page, and replaces it with `client-nojs` with JavaScript, so that it will only be left for clients woth no JS. Hence, yuo can easily style a text to show up only for those clients:

   ```
   <div class="nojs">Message</div>
   ```

And in your css:

```
    .client-js .nojs {display:none;}
```